# Why this code error when entering a 4*x symbol number or more? Converting a 16 digit number into 10 digit number

Tags: c, terminal, console, numbers

-the program takes the value of the number(16) as a string of char(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F)

-transcodes to the correct values ​​according to the character table

-converts values ​​to decimal

---

but... if:

in: A | out: 10 (+)

in: AA | out: 170(+)

in: AAA| out: ... forget answer but (+)

!!! in: AAAA| out: ERROR (-)

why?

```
#include <STDIO.H>
#include <CONIO.H>
void main()
{
    char m[100];                                // init massive chars [m] 
    gets(m);                                    // input massive [m] (16 digit number)
    int i = -1;                                 // init counter for [m] (-1 for start [i++] in 0 pos)

    while (m[i++]);                             // go to last postion in [m] and count length
    i--;                                        // step back for skip '\0'
    i--;                                        // step back for start position last char
    int s = 0;                                  // init sum  number (10 digit number)
    int v = 1;                                  // init multiplier

    while (i >= 0)                              // it is first char?
    {
        if ((m[i] >= 'A') && (m[i] <= 'F')) s += ((int)(m[i]-55) * v); // if char 'A'(65) char = (10)  * multiplier
        else s += ((int)(m[i]) * v);                                // else char 1,2,3,4,5... (1,2,)* multiplier
        v *= 16;                                // up multiplier power
        i--;                                    // char step back
    }
    printf("%i", s);                            //out sum
}
```

**after edit after comments:**

```
char m[100];
gets(m);
int i = 0;       // * "=-1" -> "0"
while (m[++i]);  // * "i++" -> "++i"
i--;

double s = 0; int v = 1;
while (i >= 0)
{
  if ((m[i] >= 'A') && (m[i] <= 'F'))  s += ((int)(m[i]-55) * v);
  if ((m[i] >= '0') && (m[i] <= '9'))  s += ((int)(m[i]-48) * v); //add this rules

  v *= 16;
  i--;
}

printf("%lf", s);
```

**+images with output results**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiyVi.jpg) & [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PN4d.jpg)

**after edit after comments:**

```
char m[100];
gets(m);
for (int i = 0; m[i] != '\0'; i += 1); // * 

unsigned long int s = 0; unsigned long int v = 1;    // *
for (int u = 0; u < i; u += 1)
{
  if ((m[u] >= 'A') && (m[u] <= 'F'))  s += ((int)(m[u]-55) * v); 
  if ((m[u] >= '0') && (m[u] <= '9'))  s += ((int)(m[u]-48) * v);

  v *= 16;
}

printf("%lu", s);                      // *
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `while (m[i++]);` is *undefined behaviour* since the first iteration tries to access `m[-1]`. BTW it appears you are using a very old compiler, and you could easily update. There are free compilers for both Linux and Windows.... also you seem to be missing `if` on line 17.

Comment: Since `i` starts at `-1`, you should replace `while (m[i++]);` with `while (m[++i]);`. In other words, _pre_-increment `i` instead of _post_-incrementing it. Then you can remove one of the `i--;` statements that follow it. `i` will be the position of the null-terminator after the `while` loop, so you only need to step back one position.

Comment: tried to change the start state to zero...

Comment: tried to change "undefined behavior"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should start at 0, not -1.

You haven't noticed it yet but your math is wrong for digits 0 through 9.

If you expect all outputs to be positive for 16 Hexidecimal characters you need an unsigned 64-bit integer (however this achieved on your platform/compiler) and you need to print unsigned long (ie not %i/%d).

Comment: While double is the right size I doubt you want the decimal.  The variable type you're looking for is `long unsigned int`.  To print it printf will be looking for `"%lu`

Comment: Almost there.  `int v` also gets really big, `unsigned long int v` and then it's working here.